# remove items when marked in the checkbox using jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

How can I remove items which are ":checked" in the checkbox using jquery. Here is the code for adding the items.

template.html

```
<h2>To Do</h2>
    <form name="checkListForm">
        <input type="text" name="checkListItem"/>
    </form>
    <div id="button">Add!</div>
    <br/>
    <div class="list"><div class="checkbox"></div></div>
```

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#button').click(function(){
var $li = $('input[name=checkListItem]');
var toAdd = $li.val();
$('.checkbox').after('<input type="checkbox"/>' + toAdd + '</br>' );}); 
if($('.checkbox').is(":checked")){$('.checkbox').child.remove();}
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because with this line:

```
$('.checkbox').after('<input type="checkbox"/>' + toAdd + '</br>');
```

you insert three dom elements: input + two text nodes I would suggest to use directly plain JS. Moreover, because you are adding element dynamically you must attach the change event handler to the upper static anchestor (i.e.: list)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#button').click(function () {
      var $li = $('input[name=checkListItem]');
      var toAdd = $li.val();
      $('.checkbox').after('<input type="checkbox"/>' + toAdd + '</br>');
  });
  $('.list').on('change', ':checkbox', function (e) {
      if (this.checked) {
          this.nextSibling.remove();
          this.nextSibling.remove();
          this.remove();
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<h2>To Do</h2>

<form name="checkListForm">
    <input type="text" name="checkListItem"/>
</form>
<div id="button">Add!</div>
<br/>

<div class="list">
    <div class="checkbox"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button').click(function() {
    var $li = $('input[name=checkListItem]');
    var toAdd = $li.val();
    $('.checkbox').prepend('<input type="checkbox" id="checklist-item-val"/>' + toAdd + '</br>');
    $('#checklist-item-val').on('click', function() {
      if ($(this).is(":checked") === true) {
        //$('.checkbox').empty();
        // What are we emptying?
      }
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>To Do</h2>
<form name="checkListForm">
  <input type="text" name="checkListItem" />
</form>
<button id="button">Add!</button>
<br/>
<div class="list">
  <div class="checkbox"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to remove the content not the checkbox.

Comment: Which 'content' are you referring to? Right now, your code is looking at the children of class "checkbox", in this case would be the checkbox that is created on click of the button.. Thanks!